# What may occur if the OS doesn't flush a TLB entry when a process does a free()?

Tags: assembly, caching, x86, cpu-architecture, tlb

What may occur if the OS doesn't flush a TLB entry when a process does a free() ?

Can the process see the stale data or can another process might see data that does not belong to it?
Will the memory be leaked?

Comment: If by `free()` you mean the opposite of `malloc()`, then the operating system rarely gets involved in a `free()` call, perhaps never on some systems.

Comment: Assuming you mean `free()` as in freeing a page, not the C library function. Yes, the original process would then still see whatever data was there until the OS gives it to some other process at which point it is typically cleared so that process will not see the old data. However once it writes new data, that may become visible in the original process.

Comment: (update: was editing to add a bit more to my answer when you accepted.  Have a look at the new version.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`free` for small allocations will normally just put the block of memory on a free-list within this process (effectively using global variables in `libc` to track this data structure).  Larger allocations will often hand the memory back to the OS using `munmap` or equivalent; I assume this is what you meant.

Normally `munmap` flushes the TLB entry for that page on this core and other cores that might be running threads of the same task.  (TLB shootdown).  But if it didn't:

Accesses on a core that had the TLB entry hot will continue to work as if that process's page-table entry for that virtual address hadn't changed.  (Until the entry gets evicted and has to get reloaded.)  Reads (and writes if it was writeable) will still be allowed.

This is super bad if the page gets reused as the kernel stack for a new process, since the process that did the `munmap` could potentially take over the kernel by modifying return addresses.  Or same thing if it was the user-space stack for a `root` process.

Or if it gets reused as pagecache for file data (like `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`), you might be able to modify the copy in RAM of that data, making other processes read data from that file that doesn't match what's on disk.  (The OS might not think the pagecache was dirty so might not write back that file data to disk.)

Or change the bytes of an executable that runs as root.  e.g. make this happen somehow, then run `sudo` if it hasn't recently been loaded from disk.  Hopefully the kernel will pick that newly-freed page for use.  Then modify the cached version of the machine code for `sudo` while it's mapped exec + read-only by the `sudo` process.  (e.g. modify it while it's asking for a password, changing what it does when you enter the wrong one.)

Or in an already-running process, maybe some of its error-handling functions are rarely executed, and are in a page with other "cold" functions which has therefore been evicted from RAM.  Feeding that process a rare kind of bad input will make it call one of those error-handling functions, triggering a hard page fault to bring it in from disk into a new page.  If it picks your page, you can now modify the machine code of one of those functions and trigger the same error again.  Boom, that process is running your machine code, successful code-injection attack.

To increase the chances of these attacks working, allocate a lot of memory so the system is low on free memory.  Then touch a few pages to prime the TLBs, and `munmap` those pages in whatever way makes the OS forget to invalidate them.  Those new pages will be most of what the OS has available for new allocations.

Obviously this would be an absolutely critical security vulnerability in any OS that tries to do any kind of isolation, and a huge correctness problem that could easily corrupt files (and filesystem metadata that was soon to be written to disk) if combined with use-after-free bugs.

Comment: This attack is even more difficult if we factor in the fact that the kernel must not touch `cr3` (or the TLB will be invalidated). I think [KPTI switches `cr3`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/pti.html) on entry/exit and, of course, scheduling out the attacker's process will also change `cr3`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Linux uses PCID (process context IDs) to avoid invalidation on some CR3 switches.  (Some other ISAs have an equivalent feature, often calling them address-space IDs aka ASIDs).  But good point; without that, you'd have to have the TLBs primed on a core running one thread, and call `munmap` from another thread.  (Since we're hypothesizing no TLB shootdown of other cores, as well as no invalidate on the current core.)  You could have multiple threads all attempting to keep various pages primed, so you had a larger attack window, one per core.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: You don't want or need the victim's allocation to be done on the same core.  Just creating its own mapping for the same page-frame that's still effectively mapped for this thread.

Comment: You are right, I forgot about the CR4.PCIDE bit. So surely invoking a syscall when KPTI is active won't flush the TLB and won't likely happen for a context switch (unless the kernel run out of PCIDs I guess). Good point about the use of other cores in case PCIDs are not used, if I understood you correctly you need to have a single thread on a specific core (to avoid context switches on said core) for this to work.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: You could start N threads, where `N = logical cores - 1 or 2`, pinning each one to a specific core, and spin in a loop touching each one of a set of pages. (To keep the TLB entries hot and re-prime them against interference from interrupt handlers or the other logical core).  Or 1 thread per phys core if TLB entries are only competitively shared.  (IIRC there was a Q&A about whether 2 logical cores could share the actual same TLB entries, and IIRC no PCIDs are per-core, and without PCIDs it was also a no.)

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Anyway, that loop can also be comparing those bytes for changes, to detect which of those virtual pages had its storage reused for something else that's now writing somewhere in the page.  (The values to compare against can be packed into bytes of registers, using integer byte compares and qword rotates, or SIMD vpcmpeqb and checking the mask, to have your compare loop able to check like 12x 8 pages using just 64-bit GP registers, leaving room for a pointer-increment loop.  Plus 15x 32 = 480 pages with YMM state.  Or more if you JIT code with constants into a largepage.)

Comment: Thanks Peter, that makes sense. I guess that then the next step would be to make a victim do some "memory spraying" to increase the odds of exploiting this UAF vulnerability.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Yeah, but only spraying methods that involve executing code in those pages are helpful, e.g. triggering calls to functions in as many different normally-cold pages as possible.  .Or that contain sensitive data, or data that you could change to exploit it.  Having allocated lots of memory, and only unmapped the pages you're scanning, those are more likely to get picked to back a new page.  If you can get the system almost swap-thrashing as you release pages one at a time, and the thrashing involves code of useful victims, you win.