# In x86_64 architecture, if I modify a PTE in the page table, when will it be sync to TLB?

Tags: x86-64, tlb, page-tables

I am designing an optimistic concurrency control mechanism to address TLB shootdowns for a specific application. The approach operates on the following principles:

The application manages data at the granularity of pages. Each page header contains the virtual address of the page.
Access to any page requires first checking the virtual address tag located in the page's header.
In the event of a page fault, the system can reassign physical pages from others without triggering a TLB flush. Due to the optimistic nature of this method, incorrect mappings in the page table can be identified.
If the virtual address matches, access continues as normal. If there is a mismatch, the page must be reloaded, and the Page Table Entry (PTE) updated. At this juncture, an outdated and invalid TLB entry may exist because we avoid TLB flushing when reassigning its physical page. After reloading the data and updating its PTE to point to a different physical page, the PTE is corrected, but the TLB entry may still be incorrect. Is a TLB flush necessary in this step?

Comment: The TLB isn't coherent with stores to PTEs, except in a very limited case on some but not all microarchitectures: https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2015/08/pagewalk-coherence/ .  The one thing that's safe to do without a TLB flush is changed a PTE from not-present to present, at least on Intel and probably AMD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to do or not do INVLPG, MOV to CR3 to minimize TLB flushing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28384234) - I'm not sure I've fully wrapped my head around your scheme, but I think the answers on the linked question cover the general rules.  Let me know if that is or isn't a duplicate. Also related: [What may occur if the OS doesn't flush a TLB entry when a process does a free()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74021499)

Comment: Also related: [Will an x86\_64 CPU notice that a page-table entry has changed to not-present while setting the dirty flag in the PTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77393983)

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer in link. In my case, there’s a case that changing a PTE from 'not-present' to 'present', but there's already a stale version of the PTE in the TLB because I hadn’t flushed it earlier in my scheme. When this happens, I have to manually flush the TLB using INVLPG. However, this situation doesn't come up often in my application. Switching a page from 'not present' to 'present' usually means the page hasn’t been used recently, making it likely that it’s already been kicked out of the TLB. So, the performance hit from flushing the TLB isn't really a big deal.

Comment: What do you think about my scheme? does it a workable scheme?

Comment: I don't understand how this can work concurrently.  If a check succeeds (this virtual address is currently mapped to a physical page holding data for that virtual address), later accesses by this thread might happen after another thread reclaims that phys page and reloads it (from disk?).  Sounds like a TOCTOU race.  Unless you have some kind of RCU-style generation numbers or other mechanism that lets you be sure no readers are still accessing a page.  Or maybe if readers do a SeqLock style check of the virtual address before and after?  But that only works for read-only access.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to introduce the background. I want to use virtual memory for DBMS's buffer manager. For some problems that you mentioned, such as pages will be reclaims by other threads and reloaded after. I have to reimplement the  reclaim schema. Worker threads and Reclaim threads need to lock page first through some bits in the page header(RW lock), then do the virtual address tag checking(the tag is viewed as part of data in the page). Locking the wrong mapping page is OK, because all physic pages are static allocated. We just need to unlock it if we found the virtual address is wrong.

Comment: I guess for a DBMS you'd need locking anyway, and page granularity could be reasonable for some workloads with some thread counts.  If locking the page is the only lock you need for a transaction, that's great, you're getting extra benefit for free if this all works out.  Evaluating the benefits of this scheme seems like enough of a different question that I don't want to answer it just in comments here, if I have time to write anything.  Maybe edit this question to ask about performance (since it's currently just a duplicate with some interesting background motivation) or ask a new one.

Comment: OK, I will edit this question later. But before that, I need time to do some basic microbenchmarks.